# Length of a line inside a rectangle

Tags: calculus, geometry

Given the width and height of a rectangle, and equation of a line, how can I efficiently find the total length of the line when it is inside the rectangle?

The rectangle is at the origin of thethe referencial.

Input 800 widht 400 height and a line y=-0.5x + 375 would give me length 838,53.

I have tried intersecting with y=0 and y=H to find the intersection points but it doenst work sometimes. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: It's good that you have written down what you've tried - but can you please elaborate on "it doesn't work sometimes"? Can you give an example where it doesn't work? The algebra of what you have described looks fine to me.

Comment: Because sometimes the line doesnt intersect y=0 or y=H on a coordinate that is inside the rectangle.

Comment: If the lines don't intersect inside the rectangle, then how can it be inside the rectangle? It's only logical for your formula to not work because the condition "they intersect inside the rectangle" doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah but in the case they dont intersect the y axis inside the rectangle I have to check the, x axis. I thought about arc length formula but it only allows from interval of on of thr axis

Comment: solve $y=0.5x+375$ and $x=800$, get a coordinate, then solve $y=0.5x+375$ and $x=800$ and $y=400$ get another coordinate, find length

Comment: I have to do tons of ifs statements, and how do I know which axis to intersect?

Comment: Given any line of the form $a x + b y = t$ where $a, b > 0$, the length
of it inside the rectangle $[0,w] \times [0,h]$, has following decomposition:
$$\ell = \ell_{00} - \ell_{w0} - \ell_{0h} + \ell_{wh}$$ 
where $\ell_{pq} = \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{ab}\max(t - (ap+bq),0)$ is the length of $L$ inside $[p,\infty) \times [q,\infty)$.

Comment: I understand, what if a is less than 0?

Comment: If $a$ is negative, one can change variable to $(x',y',t') = (w-x,y,t-aw)$ and look at intersection of rectangle with the line $|a|x' + by' = t'$ instead.

Comment: You can use a variant of the formula for the signed distance from a point to a line to determine which edges are intersected by the line.

Answer (score 1):

The rectangle has four corners, numbered as $(0,1,2,3)$.
The equation of a straight line divides the plane into a negative ( ≤ ) and a positive ( > ) region.
The line itself is the place where the equation equals zero ( ≤ ). Each of the corners of the rectangle
is in the negative ( ≤ ) or in the positive ( > ) region of the straight line.
A full solution of the problem requires that a number of different cases shall be distinguished.
A picture says more than a thousand words.

[image]

Mapping to the binary number system ensures that none of these sixteen cases will be omitted by accidence.
Employing symmetry, it turns out that the 16 cases can be collected into three classes.

```
   binary   3 2 1 0  class
 0  0000    ≤ ≤ ≤ ≤    0
 1  0001    ≤ ≤ ≤ >    1
 2  0010    ≤ ≤ > ≤    1
 3  0011    ≤ ≤ > >    2
 4  0100    ≤ > ≤ ≤    1
 5  0101    ≤ > ≤ >    2
 6  0110    ≤ > > ≤    0
 7  0111    ≤ > > >    1
 8  1000    > ≤ ≤ ≤    1
 9  1001    > ≤ ≤ >    0
10  1010    > ≤ > ≤    2
11  1011    > ≤ > >    1
12  1100    > > ≤ ≤    2
13  1101    > > ≤ >    1
14  1110    > > > ≤    1
15  1111    > > > >    0
```

Now it's only a matter of finding the intersection of two lines for the classes (1) and (2), none for class (0).
Accompanying source code will be available at [MSE publications / references 2021](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2021/index.htm).
Here is some output, augmented with numbering of the 3 classes.

[image]